# Replace multiple string values in the same custom field in SQL db

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom field called 'variations', and inside it has colors (comma seperated) like "Black, Red, Blue".
I need to replace the colors into another language on a daily basis via a cron job. For one single color change, this works to change Black into Noir:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, 'Black', 'Noir')
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'variations'
```

Everything is all and well but i would like to replace more than one color inside this same query. I prefer not to have 20 similar queries to cover all 20 possible color changes.

Is something like this possible?

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, 'Black', 'Noir'), (meta_value, 'Green', 'Vert') 
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'variations'
```

I don't have a test system and i don't want to possibly mess up my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this, using your last return of the REPLACE into a new REPLACE

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
 SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(  meta_value, 
                                      'Black', 
                                      'Noir'
                            ), 
                            'Geen', 
                            'Vert'),
                        'Blue',
                        'Blu')
 WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'variations'
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks. I'll mark as correct in a few mins.

Comment: I seem to run into some problems when adding a third color to change. I'm certain i followed the right formatting. Could you please give me an example with 3 colors, so i can take it from there.

Comment: Updated for 3, just put another `REPLACE(` at the start and and `, 'orig', ' repl')` at the end

Answer (score 1):

To give you confidence in what an `UPDATE` query might do there's almost always a `SELECT` that can form that you can see the data you'd generate with it. In this case you could do:

```
SELECT meta_value, REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(  meta_value, 
                                  'Black', 
                                  'Noir'
                        ), 
                        'Geen', 
                        'Vert')
FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE variations;
```